# Link to class method in Python docstring

Tags: python, spyder, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I want to add a link to a method in my class from within the docstring of another method of the same class. I want the link to work in Sphinx and preferentially also in Spyder and other Python IDEs.

I tried several options and found only one that works, but it's cumbersome.

Suppose the following structure in `mymodule.py`

```py
def class MyClass():
    def foo(self):
        print 'foo'
    def bar(self):
        """This method does the same as <link to foo>"""
        print 'foo'
```

I tried the following options for `<link to foo>`:

- `` :func:`foo` ``
- `` :func:`self.foo` ``
- `` :func:`MyClass.foo` ``
- `` :func:`mymodule.MyClass.foo` ``

The only one that effectively produces a link is `` :func:`mymodule.MyClass.foo` `` , but the link is shown as `mymodule.MyClass.foo()` and I want a link that is shown as `foo()` or `foo`. None of the options above produces a link in Spyder.

Comment: What does mean _"add ... from within"_ ??? What's the difference between a link and an hyperlink ?

Comment: I replaced `hyperlink` by `link` to avoid confusion.

Comment: I still don't understand very well your question. Do you mean that you want to perform , from Sphinx or from Spyder or from others Python IDEs, an interrogation of the docstring of the function ``bar`` that will give the information _"the function or method you search is foo"_ ?

Comment: Secondly, what difference do you make between ``mymodule.MyClass.foo()`` and ``foo()`` ? And what do you call _"display"_ ? Is it the display of a string ? Or do you want an object returned ? In this latter case, the paens at the end of ``mymodule.MyClass.foo()`` and ``foo()`` are too much.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's always hard to explain a question concisely.  I just want to have a link you can click, that will take you to the docstring of foo() (in the documentation window of the IDE, or in the html build of Sphinx).  Regarding the parentheses: they are correct: :func:`mymodule.MyClass.foo` resulted in the link having the parentheses. And I have rephrased the question slightly again.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The solution that works for Sphinx is to prefix the reference with `~`.

Per the Sphinx documentation on [Cross-referencing Syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-syntax),

> If you prefix the content with `~`, the link text will only be the last component of the target. For example, `` :py:meth:`~Queue.Queue.get` ``  will refer to `Queue.Queue.get` but only display `get` as the link text.

So the answer is:

```py
class MyClass():
    def foo(self):
        print 'foo'
    def bar(self):
        """This method does the same as :func:`~mymodule.MyClass.foo`"""
        print 'foo'
```

This results in an HTML looking like this : `This method does the same as foo()`, and  `foo()` is a link.

However, note that this may not display in Spyder as a link.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) @saroele I plan to improve this situation in the future. I totally agree it'd be really cool to have it ;)

Comment: You can do it with the [`:any:` role](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-any) - see the note about `default_setting`.

Comment: is it possible to cross-reference without using the full module path?

Comment: @Jonathan : in the autodoc.rst I use the currentmodule :  
.. currentmodule:: mymodule
.. autosummary:: 
   mymodule.MyClass
and in the docstring, using simply the short name is ok.

Comment: It seems `:func:\`~foo\`` will do, if that foo() method is within the same class as current method bar().

Comment: Instead of `:func:`, I found it has to be `:meth:`.

Answer (score 57):

If you want to manually specify the text of the link you can use:

```
:func:`my text <mymodule.MyClass.foo>`
```

For more information, checkout [Cross-referencing Python objects](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects).

Comment: This works, thanks.  By looking at the link, I found out that prefixing the reference with ``~`` is closer to what I need.  I have put that in a separate answer.  It still doesn't work in Spyder however...

Answer (score -9):

It seems to me that you just have to add `__name__` or `__doc__` to  your expression to obtain what you want.
I'm still not sure to have correctly understood the aim

```
class MyClass():
    def foo(self):
        """I am the docstring of foo"""
        print 'foo'
    def bar(self):
        """This method does the same as <link to foo>"""
        print 'foo'

print
print MyClass.foo
print MyClass.foo.__name__
print MyClass.foo.__doc__
print
print MyClass.__dict__['foo']
print MyClass.__dict__['foo'].__name__
print MyClass.__dict__['foo'].__doc__
```

result

```
<unbound method MyClass.foo>
foo
I am the docstring of foo

<function foo at 0x011C27B0>
foo
I am the docstring of foo
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question: I want to have a link (hyperlink) in the html of my documentation built by Sphinx.

Comment: You are right, I miss the point. And that's because I don't know Sphinx. so I tried to install Sphinx. But I didn't succeed. I'm on Windows and I tried to use sphinx-quickstart as said in the doc. But I think I have a misunderstanding of the intsallation process.  I can't help you , sorry. I dunno what must be undertsood by 'hyperlink' in the context of Sphinx.