# PyCharm docstrings linking to classes

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

IntelliJ IDEA allows for linking to other methods in Java document comments. This allows me to move the cursor over a symbol and jump to the definition using a keyboard shortcut, as well as holding down ctrl while hovering with the mouse displaying an underline under the symbol which is clickable. For example:

```
/**
  * This is a link to a method {@link #setBalance}
  */
```

I am trying to achieve this in Python with PyCharm. I've tried various things from other answers without any luck. Here are some attempts:

```
def my_func(my_arg):
    '''
    Convert a S{decimal.Decimal} to an :ref:`int`.

    This method imports a module called :mod:``django``.

    Sometimes we might call :func:`~utils.error` to raise an {@link Exception}.
    '''
```

None of these autocomplete or create a hyperlink.

Could it be that PyCharm simply hasn't implemented this functionality (yet)?

This question is similar to [Link to class method in python docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289806/link-to-class-method-in-python-docstring) but the answers don't seem to apply to PyCharm.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445007/pycharm-docstring-code-references-and-docstring-inheritance

Answer (score 24):

I contacted support and it turns out it hasn't been implemented.

I have created a feature request on their issue tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14743

**Update:**

original feature request is marked as a duplicate of

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27635

State: In progress

Comment: 2018 and still no fix or assignment.

Comment: End of 2020 and still no implementetion

Comment: Still no implementation as of mid 2022.  I don't think this will be added.

Comment: 2023 April, still not implemented

Comment: 2024 February, still nothing

Answer (score 22):

```
def die_hard(self):
    """
    Throws a :class:`NakatomiPlazaError`.
    """
    raise NakatomiPlazaError('Yippee ki-yay')
```

Worked for me.

Comment: I tried this, ctrl-click on the class in the doc-string doesn't go to definition.

Comment: This works, but curiously only in the main body of a docstring. For some reason it e.g. doesn't work in a line after `:param name_of_param:`

Comment: This worked for me in Intellij 2020.3 too

Comment: @z33k indeed, this is being tracked at [PY-27635](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27635#focus=Comments-27-4916931.0-0).

Comment: If the class is in another file/module/package, the link won't work. It is possible to let PyCharm know by importing that class in a `TYPE_CHECKING` guard: `if TYPE_CHECKING:` `from .some_module import AClass`. Add a `# noqa` comment next to this seemingly useless import if PyCharm attempts to remove it on Save/Reformat Code/Optimize Imports/etc.