# Reference in docstring / quick view documentation not working in Pycharm

Tags: python, reference, pycharm, docstring

In PyCharm, I want to use the docstrings to create useful quick-view documentation (the kind of documentation showing up if you hover your mouse over an object). However, I am not able to get a working reference to anything - eg. classes, functions, types...

For example, I can do

```
import time
def foo(a):
    """ Useful short description here.
        
        :param a: Here should be a reference to a function, e.g. :func:time.sleep
    """
```

The quick view documentation is showing up - everything is working as expected except the references. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Honestly, I'm am bit lost at the moment. I read about Sphinx, docstring, docutils, but they look all kinda the same? Also, I'm not sure if the issue is related to some external tool, to PyCharm, to my syntax - or if I'm just missing something insanely obvious...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475432/pycharm-docstrings-linking-to-classes seems like still not implemented, despite being requested in 2014...

Comment: Oh, well - this explains of course why it's not working. Thanks for the reply!