# Adjust VSCode tooltip markdown to link to objects

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

### Context

For Python-development I use both Microsofts *VSCode* and JetBrains *Pycharm*.

Both IDEs support markdown in the tooltip of the docstrings. Anyhow, in VSCode the markdown for code is the commonly used backtick "`" while the JetBrain-IDE(s) use square brackets "[]".
When switching between IDEs it becomes a little annoying that I cannot figure out a way to enable VSCode using the brackets instead of the backticks as well.

Here is some screenshot viusalizing the "issue":

[image]

### Questions

**First question:** *Does anybody know a VSCode option to either change this in the settings or some plugin allowing to do so?*

While being at this topic: Other IDEs also allow not to only highlight in the tooltip (like "test" in the screenshot) but actually link it to the respective declaration/definition.

**Second question:** *Does any option/plugin for VSCode exist allowing linked references in the tooltips?*

While these seem to be rather simple high level questions I couldn't find any answers/resolutions so far...

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I don't have any ideas at present. I will upload it to GitHub to request function addition.
For the second question,I think Sphinx may help you. In Sphinx, you could prefix the reference with "~". You can refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289806/link-to-class-method-in-python-docstring)

Comment: According to the feedback of Github,  "[]" is not standard markdown for code snippets. So this feature will not be supported.

Comment: Thank you for asking on Github. Anyhow, it isn't a necessity that this a default or that this syntax "[]" is available per se. It would be fully sufficient if markdown components could be adjustable. I'll try if a Sphinx-implementation for VSCode does the trick though; thx for the hint!

Comment: Does my solution solve your question2?