# vscode : Make link that when clicked open a script to a specific definition

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperlink, comments

As the title says, it is possible to make a clickable link inside a comment to a script at a specific class definition?

I've added a function inside a python method of a class, I've put a comment using `""" """` to display a description, inside the description I talk about another class but I would like to make a link on the class name that when clicked open the script at the line that define the class.

If vscode does not have this feature, do exist a plugin for it?

Comment: it is a feature the Language Service Provider must implement

Comment: loosely related: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/discussions/4402. also, [Sphinx has cross-referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21289806/11107541), but I'm not sure if VS Code supports this. If it doesn't, you could [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new?assignees=&labels=classify%2C+feature-request&projects=&template=3_feature_request.md) to have the hover info widget contributed by the Python support this. If you do, please [edit] your question post to add a link to your feature-request issue ticket for posterity.

Comment: @starball , so vscode currently does not have this feature? But can be requested or installed via a plugin?